Usar addEventListener sem especificar o objeto alvo
Quando você usa addEventListener diretamente, sem especificar explicitamente o objeto alvo (como window ou document), pode haver algum problema ou impacto no funcionamento do evento? Em que casos isso funcionaria corretamente e quais as implicações de não indicar o alvo explicitamente?
Considere os seguintes exemplos, ambos aparentemente funcionando:
Exemplo 1:
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Window clicked!');
});

Exemplo 2:
addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Window clicked!');
});

Não encontrei nada falando sobre as implicações de omitir um objeto alvo. Eu imagino que, ao usar addEventListener, ele deve procurar no escopo e encontrar diretamente no window. Sendo assim, o alvo, no fim, vai acabar sendo o window, mas não sei se, em algum cenário, fazer isso traria erros.

Importante: o 2º exemplo não omite alvo, só deixa implícito. Continua sendo método de window ou de qualquer elemento de escopo global no ambiente. Nem tem a ver com eventos isso, é uma característica geral do motor, e as implicações de omitir são as mesmas de Preciso omitir a palavra "window" quando chamar uma função do objeto global? - e voltando ao addEventListener, a MDN deixa claro que é método do alvo, não uma função solta: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - em resumo, SEMPRE tem alvo, resta você garantir que seja o esperado.
